# How do I grab the hrefs of all the job postings in a search from Indeed using Beautifulsoup in Python?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am practicing using Beautifulsoup and scraping data from Indeed. I am a relatively novice Python coder and am new to Beautifulsoup but I've been able to figure out most of what I'm trying to do except grabbing the hrefs of each job posting within the search results on Indeed. Most of the information is nested within this div class="job_seen_beacon" as shown in the attached image:

[Indeed Job Posting Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I33wR.png)

The href that I need is right above in the a-tag (for the first posting, and is in similar location for the rest of the postings). It seems the job links all have a similar format (indeed url + /pagead/+unique identifiers). So far I have been able to grab the first of these hrefs by doing:

```
link1 = soup.find('a',{'class':'tapItem'}).get('href')

indeed_link='https://indeed.com'

job_full_link=indeed_link + link1
```

which returns:

```
https://indeed.com/pagead/clk?mo=r&ad=-6NYlbfkN0BYwoYS5IKUNHtA0a2VJhnZaPA0uEqIlEtc2XBlIiwK2z_X_68BR8FDAa4lu8N0xeCPwzwEnA8fXiK4iQSEmPwTPepfI6vD2vAIjZkkxpjBBMQUv338KUlip1EOk09_cn2LwmJdZfFHW0-AI7SZQhu1kIQsWTuRTOsU1vuAYvarCELllpMjt_GHp_65BONysimbVWU32exjeilFXm_q51osn1zTWwhznG16bEYsjNkVT231ngYVuvoC3RBW5qn2IB0yR0T3ppMCF4nVaIMUg2yvjXVLsbdbNYgj_ckFk4jrStGLrXIoTrozdnqm3fxToPHdshPAVD7771cWJDflltxdMjmVEdP2f74y2Gc1IAJBaNtq-GweslVoetCVqneDAWtDx4fDODfUv44tpOPE3rZycEp6SLUjAjcYpUW9qG5AJjaUOIU6MwVxZe6Xi1nECNwvoZrEpYXkCBvC3KbMg4DdMhoni660wPq8oW4DXKuz0ffj50lr_cNu&p=0&fvj=1&vjs=3
```

For starters, I'm not sure that is the best way to do it. There are other hrefs within that 'tapItem' class so I feel like my code only seems like it is working since that is the first href. I'm trying to create a loop to snag all of the job links and append them which is where I'm stuck now and am not sure how to set that up. Any ideas/pointers?

This is my first post on StackOverflow so let me know if I need to add more context! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Note

**`find()` / `select_one()`**

Returns only the first occurrence of your selection

**`find_all()` / `select()`**

Returns a resultset of all occurrences it could find with your selection

#### How to fix ?

Use `find_all()` / `select()` to generate a resultset you could iterate later

#### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = requests.get('https://de.indeed.com/Jobs?q=Data%20Engeneering&from=sug&vjk=7fb07edbe78d1d3a').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

indeed_link='https://indeed.com'
links = [indeed_link+a['href'] for a in soup.select('a.tapItem')]

for link in links:
    do something....
```

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!